# ArrayList<ParseQuery> Unsure how to use?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parse-platform

I know this is a noob question but I can't find any answers anywhere else. I am new to programming so please explain thoroughly.

I am working with parse.com. I am trying to get a query that has anywhere from 3-20 objects. I need to display the objects. After trying things, debugging and doing research, I realize that it is coming to me as an `ArrayList` . I don't know how to get the objects out and properly display them. I cant find any examples in the docs on parse.com. Here is my code, I noted what is the `ArrayList` But not sure where to go with it now.

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("FightersDB");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> FightersDB/*This is my ArrayList*/, ParseException e) {
    if (e==null){
        Log.d("Info", "No Errors");

        //This is where I don't know what to do to retrieve my objects.
        //Inside each object, I have strings named "Name" "WeightClass" "Record" "Age"
        TextView tv; 
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(name + " " + fightersWeight + " " + record + " " + age);

    }else {
        Log.d("Info", "Not Retrieved successfully");
    }
    }

});
```

Comment: What you need is an ArrayAdapter [link] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

First you create your list like this :   *ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();*

and then you set your ArrayAdapter

Comment: Check this example too: [here](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create your ArrayList :

```
ArrayList<ParseObject> FightersDB = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
```

Then adapt your items to the layout :

```
ArrayAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ParseObject>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.id1, FightersDB );
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

There are some default layouts for android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html

You will also need to change your xml layout file by adding a ListView View :

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/id1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the setListAdapter(adapter); It's not quite working

Comment: Well I was able to get it to work with a variant of your code... slightly. But its now a new question, so [take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014244/using-listview-multiple-times).