# Using ListView multiple times

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

I am new to programming, so please explain. But I have a a few objects I am pulling off of parse.com. When I get an object, I call this method. But my problem is, every time this method is called, it replaces the first item each time. I know this is an easy fix, I just need a bit of help.

```
private void display(Object name, Object weightClass, Object record, int count) {       


    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    String fightCard = (name).toString();
    listAdapter.add(fightCard); 
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();          
 }
```

Also, I know this is another question entirely, but I know I will need to look up ways to customize my list view, I am wanting to change colors and sizes. Does anyone know some good links to learn how to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You're *recreating* the adapter every time you add an object. This is expected behaviour. I'd be surprised if two items showed up.

Comment: Create the adapter before I call this method then?

Comment: If you have time, consider watching this video: [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70).

Comment: I guess method *display()*  is inside a loop  and each time you get variable **name** and you want to add it to the list, right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I will add **name**, **weightClass**, and **record**. I just haven't put those in until I figure out how to do it. I want those all on one line.

Comment: Create a new Object. Add all of them in a class like : public class DataItem { private String name; private String weightClass; private String record; } and then change your arrayList to : 
ArrayList<DataItem> your_array_list = new ArrayList<DataItem>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider change the method so it will return each time a String.
So it will be :

```
private String display(Object name, Object weightClass, Object record, int count) {       

String fightCard = (name).toString();
return fightCard;
}
```

Then within onCreate() :

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

 "loop here -> get each String and add it to list : ( your_array_list.add( fightCard ) ) "

        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

     lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

step by step :
1. declare your listView item by finding the id in your layout file 
2. declare an ArrayList you will use to store your items
3. add items to your arraylist. Here you get them from a method so loop until you add them all
4. declare ArrayAdapter 
5. set the data behind your listView

Comment: Since you're following all my questions thus far, check out [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015179/right-and-left-align-in-a-single-listview) that is similar. Thanks :D

Comment: hope my answers really help and you are making a progress :)

Comment: Yeah you're really helping!

Answer (score 2):

The below should be created outside the method first.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

And then pass the adapter into the method

```
display(name,weightClass,record,count, adapter);
```

**Or**

Just have the adapter global, for access within the method.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
   listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
   list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
//whatever else you want
```

}

And then within your method:

```
private void display(Object name, Object weightClass, Object record, int count) {       

String fightCard = (name).toString();
listAdapter.add(fightCard); 
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

After this, every time you call this method, the data will be pumped into the adapter.

Hit me up if you're still confused/stuck.

Comment: Um yeah, How would I make it Global?

Answer (score 1):

i think you are missing an argument on `ArrayAdapter` try this:

```
ArrayList<String> namesArray = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesArray);
```

and every time you have a new item add it to namesArray, and then call

```
namesArray.add((name).toString());
```

`listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

because if you do this: `listAdapter.add(fightCard);` it will keep replacing the existing item in your ListView;

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! That cleared a lot up for me!