# Right and left align in a single ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am setting a `listView` dynamically. I will have two things shown on each line that I will be receiving from `parse.com`. I want the first thing to be left aligned and blue, with the second thing right aligned and red. I will have two arrays, `firstArray`, and `secondArray`. I found lots of ways to do this, but none dynamically. How should I go about doing this, or I can do it in `xml`?

**Updated**

This is my `xml` after that tutorial posted by @t0s

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="2dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/column1"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#0000FF"
    android:gravity="left"
    />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/center"
    android:text="VS"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
   />
       <TextView
    android:id="@+id/column2"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:gravity="right"
   />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and my java

```
 ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

                ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.mylist, namesArray);
                list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

 //find my objects off parse, and call this method

private String display(Object name, Object record,
         ArrayAdapter listAdapter) {

    String fightCard = (name).toString();
    namesArray.add((name).toString() +" " + (record).toString());
    return fightCard;
}
```

Comment: Do it in XML! much easier :), Please provide your xml for your listview row

Comment: Do you have a custom row xml?

Comment: No I don't... what is a custom row?

Comment: Simple example [here](http://hashfold.com/techfold/android-creating-multi-column-layout-with-arrayadapter/). You need to use [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#pubctors)

Comment: Yeah, follow the tut by t0s, reply if lost, by applying a custom row layout for the listview, you can specifically define how you want your rows to look like.

Comment: In a few words : Create a new xml layout which stands for every row, if for example you got 3 TextViews in a row you are going to add them in your new xml layout file. Each of them will have an id. SimpleAdapter does the rest.

Comment: so remove my ArrayAdapter?

Comment: yes. Change it with SimpleAdapter

Comment: I updated the xml, but not sure what to fix on the java. sorry the java is a mess.

Comment: Just to clarify: the xml you posted is the new xml layout which will apply only for each row. You have kept the main.xml with the list id ?

Comment: Yes, I kept my main.xml. only added this xml

Comment: @ChadD.Bingham I added all the files you need. Please check them or try to run them and I will post some comments later. t0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well my code is a mess. 
Check the tutorial here is [[very simple]](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#tutorial_ownadapter)

Ok Chad check here the code :

Main Activity :

```
package org.example.chad;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


private ArrayList<DataItem> data = new ArrayList<DataItem>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //create Objects
    DataItem obj1 = new DataItem("name1", "record1");
    DataItem obj2 = new DataItem("name2", "record2");
    DataItem obj3 = new DataItem("name3", "record3");
    DataItem obj4 = new DataItem("name4", "record4");
    DataItem obj5 = new DataItem("name5", "record5");
    //add the to ArrayList
    data.add(obj1);
    data.add(obj2);
    data.add(obj3);
    data.add(obj4);
    data.add(obj5);


        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.row, data);
        setListAdapter(adapter);        

}
```

}

**main.xml** :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**DataItem** :

```
package org.example.chad;

public class DataItem {
private String name;
private String record;

public DataItem(){

}

public DataItem(String n, String r ){
    this.name = n;
    this.record = r;
}

public String getname() {
    return name;
}

public void setname(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getrecord() {
    return record;
}

public void setrecord(String record) {
    this.record = record;
}
```

}

CustomAdapter :

```
package org.example.chad;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataItem> {
   private ArrayList<DataItem> objects;

   public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<DataItem>     objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
}

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  View v = convertView;
  if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }


  DataItem i = objects.get(position);

if (i != null) {
    TextView nameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView recordView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.record);

    if (nameView != null){
        nameView.setText(i.getname());
    }
    if (recordView != null){
        recordView.setText(i.getrecord());
    }

}

return v;
  }
}
```

and **row.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/name"
      android:layout_width="100sp"
      android:layout_height="20sp"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/record"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In a couple of hours I will add some comments.
The result is here
[image]

Comment: This is all way out of my league... Haha

Comment: Hi @ChadD.Bingham sorry for late replay I was busy. 1st I can't access the pastebin it says is a private paste, make it public. 2nd I will Edit my answer to add some comments explaining my code. 3rd is my result similar to what you want to achieve? If it is then I will try to help you step by step.

Comment: I'll send you an answer. check your email

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken you have to extend `BaseAdapter` class so you have a custom Adapter for your  ListView, it is not possible to add two array items to a ListView without creating a custom adapter.

here is a [tutorial.](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/56268.aspx)

is not as hard as it looks like. Hope it helps.